# Sincronizar un repo de GIT con FTP

Tags: git, git-push

Tenemos el siguiente escenario:

1. Servidor con fuentes al que se accede via FTP.
2. Un repositorio git sincronizado con dicho repositorio

Durante el día los cambios se realizan en el FTP (sincronización de archivos)
En la noche se toman los cambios y se realiza un commit en GIT desde una máquina local
Con distinto huso horario otra persona toma los cambios del FTP
Hace cambios en el FTP
Debe subir dichos cambios al GIT
necesitamos subir al GIT todo el trabajo que hace la segunda persona para reiniciar el ciclo.

Con las siguientes restricciones:
No se puede instalar git en la maquina que tiene el FTP
Se debe mantener la fecha de modificación de los arhivos en el FTP y no la fecha en que se realizó el commit.

Probamos hacer:

```
git merge -Xours --progress --stat pero cuando da conflictos (y deberia ignorarlos en favor de los nuestros se bloquea)
git stash + drop
git pull -Xours --progress -v --no-rebase "origin" (no borra cambios locales)
```

Debe haber una solucion canónica a este problema
Agradecemos la ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Se que esta pregunta fue de hace ya mucho tiempo pero como he visto que no hay respuesta aqui mi aporte, para usar git y FTP se puede usar lo siguiente.

Git-FTP

[Git-FTP](https://git-ftp.github.io/) es un cliente FTP escrito en shell.

Permite transferir solamente aquellos ficheros que han sido modificados en el repositorio Git desde la última actualización. Sin importar en que rama se esté trabajando, git-ftp permite identificar los ficheros cambiados.
¿Cómo funciona git-ftp?

Git-FTP utiliza como parámetros para su funcionamiento las credenciales del servidor FTP y la ubicación del repositorio git donde desea realizar el despliegue. Esto le permite posicionarse en el directorio para obtener los ficheros modificados y utiliza las credenciales para establecer la conexión.

Para identificar los ficheros que tienen que ser actualizados Git-FTP crea un fichero llamado .git-fpt.log en el hosting donde guarda el valor SHA1 que identifica al commit de git. Por tal motivo, en la próxima actualización puede establecer la diferencia entre el commit actual del repositorio y el que está en el servidor para conocer los ficheros que han sido modificados.
Inconvenientes de git-ftp

Git-FTP no significa tener un control de versiones en el servidor. Los cambios realizados de forma manual en el alojamiento web no serán detectados por esta herramienta y pudiera implicar posibles actualizaciones no deseadas de ficheros.

Se recomienda para el uso de Git-FTP utilizar siempre el mismo flujo para el despliegue.